# How do I write over a triangle-shaped div using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes, text-rotation

I'm currently trying to write words over a triangle-shaped div that I created using CSS.

Here:

```css
.triangle-topright {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid gray;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-topright">view</div>
```

As you can see, view is misplaced as I want it to be inside the shape. I also want it to rotate so It's nice for the eye. I know that text rotation goes something like this (example):

```
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Can I achieve the goal using CSS or do I need to add some JS?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can achieve it using CSS only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pseudo elements

**DEMO - 1**

```css
.triangle-topright {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 64px;
}

.triangle-topright:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  border-right: 100px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-topright">view</div>
```

**DEMO - 2**

```css
.triangle-topright {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center
}

.triangle-topright:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid gray;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-topright">view</div>
```

**DEMO - 3**

```css
.triangle-topright {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center
}

.triangle-topright:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid gray;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-topright">view</div>
```

**DEMO - 4**

```css
.triangle-topright {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center
}

.triangle-topright:before {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid gray;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-topright">view</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers above achieve the same already. Here is my JSfiddle you can play around with.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmtg1oc8/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid gray;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}

.content {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

And the html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="triangle"></div>
    <div class="content">hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an example of doing it with just CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/KV84j/14/).

HTML

```
<section class="page_block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="verticaltext">
                    Vert Text
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <p>Column Somethin?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.page_block {
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
}
#header { 
    position: relative; 
}
.verticaltext {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: right, top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:right, top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:right, top;
    position: absolute; 
    color: #ed217c;
}
```